# Sorting in elastic Search by Location and getting error while location lat and long is not coming

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have tried with the below code full fill my location sorting requirements in elastic search, when location is coming then it's working fine, but when location lat and long is not coming then my Nest c# code giving me the Exception

```
.Sort(s = >s.Ascending(fs = >fs.current_stage).Field(gh = >{
    var query = new SortFieldDescriptor < CarSearchRequest > ();
    if (searchAjaxRequest.sortingFilter != null) {
        if (searchAjaxRequest.sortingFilter == "titleasc") {
            query = gh.Field(tt = >tt.model).Order(SortOrder.Ascending);
        }
        else if (searchAjaxRequest.sortingFilter == "titledsc") {
            query = gh.Field(tt = >tt.model).Order(SortOrder.Descending);
        }
        else if (searchAjaxRequest.sortingFilter == "priceasc") {
            query = gh.Field(tt = >tt.price).Order(SortOrder.Ascending);
        }
        else if (searchAjaxRequest.sortingFilter == "Pricedsc") {
            query = gh.Field(tt = >tt.price).Order(SortOrder.Descending);
        }
        else if (searchAjaxRequest.sortingFilter == "Kmasc") {
            query = gh.Field(tt = >tt.kmRun).Order(SortOrder.Ascending);
        }
        else if (searchAjaxRequest.sortingFilter == "kmdsc") {
            query = gh.Field(tt = >tt.kmRun).Order(SortOrder.Descending);
        }
        else if (searchAjaxRequest.sortingFilter == "introductiondateasc") {
            query = gh.Field(tt = >tt.mfYear).Order(SortOrder.Ascending);
        }
        else if (searchAjaxRequest.sortingFilter == "introductiondatedesc") {
            query = gh.Field(tt = >tt.mfYear).Order(SortOrder.Descending);
        }
        return query;
    }
    else if (searchAjaxRequest.category != null) {
        if (searchAjaxRequest.category == "recentViewed") {
            query = gh.Field(tt = >tt.createdDate).Order(SortOrder.Descending);
        }
        else if (searchAjaxRequest.category == "topRated") {
            query = gh.Field(tt = >tt.overallRating).Order(SortOrder.Descending);
        }
        return query;
    }

    return query;
}).GeoDistance(g = >{
    var locatioSorting = new SortGeoDistanceDescriptor < CarSearchRequest > ();
    if (searchAjaxRequest.location != null) {
        locatioSorting = g.Field(ab = >ab.location).Order(SortOrder.Ascending).Unit(DistanceUnit.Kilometers).Mode(SortMode.Min).Points(new GeoLocation(searchAjaxRequest.location.lat, searchAjaxRequest.location.lon));
    }
    return locatioSorting;
})));
```

Exception which is coming after null handle in my code.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Nest.FieldResolver.Resolve(Field field)
   at Nest.SortJsonConverter.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<WriteJson>b__0(JsonWriter w)
   at Nest.ReserializeJsonConverter`2.Reserialize(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonSerializer serializer, Action`1 inlineWriter)
   at Nest.SortJsonConverter.WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
   at Elastic.Internal.JsonNet.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeConvertable(JsonWriter writer, JsonConverter converter, Object value, JsonContract contract, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Elastic.Internal.JsonNet.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Elastic.Internal.JsonNet.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Elastic.Internal.JsonNet.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Elastic.Internal.JsonNet.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Nest.InternalSerializer.Serialize[T](T data, Stream writableStream, SerializationFormatting formatting)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.SerializableData`1.Write(Stream writableStream, IConnectionConfigurationValues settings)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpWebRequestConnection.Request[TResponse](RequestData requestData)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.CallElasticsearch[TResponse](RequestData requestData)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.Request[TResponse](HttpMethod method, String path, PostData data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)
# Inner Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Nest.FieldResolver.Resolve(Field field)
   at Nest.SortJsonConverter.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<WriteJson>b__0(JsonWriter w)
   at Nest.ReserializeJsonConverter`2.Reserialize(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonSerializer serializer, Action`1 inlineWriter)
   at Nest.SortJsonConverter.WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
   at Elastic.Internal.JsonNet.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeConvertable(JsonWriter writer, JsonConverter converter, Object value, JsonContract contract, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Elastic.Internal.JsonNet.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Elastic.Internal.JsonNet.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Elastic.Internal.JsonNet.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Elastic.Internal.JsonNet.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Nest.InternalSerializer.Serialize[T](T data, Stream writableStream, SerializationFormatting formatting)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.SerializableData`1.Write(Stream writableStream, IConnectionConfigurationValues settings)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpWebRequestConnection.Request[TResponse](RequestData requestData)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.CallElasticsearch[TResponse](RequestData requestData)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.Request[TResponse](HttpMethod method, String path, PostData data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)
# Exception:
Elasticsearch.Net.UnexpectedElasticsearchClientException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Nest.FieldResolver.Resolve(Field field)
   at Nest.SortJsonConverter.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<WriteJson>b__0(JsonWriter w)
   at Nest.ReserializeJsonConverter`2.Reserialize(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonSerializer serializer, Action`1 inlineWriter)
   at Nest.SortJsonConverter.WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
   at Elastic.Internal.JsonNet.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeConvertable(JsonWriter writer, JsonConverter converter, Object value, JsonContract contract, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Elastic.Internal.JsonNet.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Elastic.Internal.JsonNet.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Elastic.Internal.JsonNet.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Elastic.Internal.JsonNet.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Nest.InternalSerializer.Serialize[T](T data, Stream writableStream, SerializationFormatting formatting)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.SerializableData`1.Write(Stream writableStream, IConnectionConfigurationValues settings)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpWebRequestConnection.Request[TResponse](RequestData requestData)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.CallElasticsearch[TResponse](RequestData requestData)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.Request[TResponse](HttpMethod method, String path, PostData data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: Please can you put together a small but complete example that reproduces the issue you're having. At the moment, only partial information is provided that is syntactically incorrect too, so it's difficult to help. My suspicion is that the `.GeoDistance()` should not even be called if the input has no location, but right now it returns a `SortGeoDistanceDescriptor<CarSearchRequest>()` with no `Field` set when no location is provided

Comment: Thanks for the replying. now sharing the complete code sample for the Nest lambda query